# CSS Layout Constrained To Browser Window?

Tags: css, html

I have spent at least 10 hours trying to figure out how to achieve the depicted layout with HTML and CSS and I've come up with nothing. I have searched endlessly and while a lot of answers seem to come close, I can't quite tweak it into place.

I just want to make a simple browser app that has a header, footer, menu bar on the left, and a map with a nav bar as the main content. I want the map to be constrained to the content div and not just "overflowing-but-hidden". And I would love if there were never any scrollbars, if everything just fit in place. Is this possible with CSS?

[image]

PLEASE PLEASE, I'm dying here!

Comment: How close is this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html ?

Comment: You need to show some code so users can point you in the right direction

Comment: The fluid example is close, but I'd love if it could all be simply contained in the browser with no need to scroll  --  like Google Maps,  how could I make my own Google map with a header, side menu, and map, all constrained to the browser window?

Comment: What you need to do is start doing some beginner html/css tutorials. This is all basic stuff. And reading your question, it's quite obvious you haven't quite managed the basics. Don't take this comment as an insult. It's actually the complete opposite. I want to help you. So all I can say is; start with a solid basis and don't rush it.  

Here are some usefull links that might help you: www.codecademy.com - www.teamtreehouse.com - www.codeschool.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could just position everything fixed, it sounds to me as if you want something like that. (Concerning "never any scrollbars, everything just fit in place".)
If that is what you want, you could do something like the following:

```
body,#header,#menu,#footer,#content {
  position:fixed;
  margin:0;
  padding:0; 
}
#header {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:auto;
  height:40px; 
}
#menu {
  left:0;
  top:45px;
  bottom:35px;
  height:auto;
  width:120px; 
}
#footer {
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:auto;
  height:30px; 
}
#content {
  right:0;
  top:45px;
  bottom:35px;
  left:125px;
  min-width:200px;
  min-height:200px;
  height:auto;
  width:auto; 
}
#navbar {
  position:relative;
  height:30px;
  display:block;
  min-width:200px;
}
#map {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:auto;
  height:auto; 
}
```

With something like this, every element will be and stay in place, and just the content will resize with the window. Although I must admit, that I didn't *really* get the point of what you requested. I hope this kind of suits your needs.
To be honest, I kind of find your question a little bit odd, as you seem to be in need to learn some of the CSS basics.

Comment: Perfect, thank you sooooo much!!!! I had been trying a lot more difficult options!

Comment: Actually one sec, the map overflows! any thoughts?

Comment: There must be something inside #map that ignores the width... Try adding _overflow:auto;_ to #map. Apropos, I forgot to mention (which may be the issue too): The CSS I wrote there expects #map and #navbar actually being _children_ of #content, if that was not clear. (<div#content><div#navbar></div><div#map></div></div>, to say in pseudocode)

Comment: Thanks Adam! I tried it and the whole layout is just about there, but even with the overflow:auto, it overflows... The width seems fine, it's just the height that shoots down through the footer... Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it sounds like your issue is around the container div for the map. Try setting it's CSS properties like so:

```
.container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px; // Offset for the header 
 bottom: 100px; // Offset for the footer
 left: 200px; // Offset for the menu
 right: 0;
}
```

Then put the map inside with 100% width and height.